# Need to create new custom pages on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, web

I'm trying to create a web that have a main page, and another four sections that I want to use the same template. I've copied the 'index.php' in the theme's folder as 'index_wealth.php' and when I use a link to it I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\restimpo\index_wealth.php on line 7
```

My page starts this way:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 * @package RestImpo
 * @since RestImpo 1.0.0
*/
get_header(); ?>
```

I have to replicate the main page four times, and the header is the same in everyone, how can I do this?

Tried this but I'm just getting more errors:

```
require_once('C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\template.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\plugin.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-includes\general-template.php');
get_header();
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to prepare two page templates. One is for main page and one for the pages with same layout.

Just modify the upper content of your index_wealth.php like this :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Main Page Template
*/
get_header(); ?>
```

After this Go to admin => Pages( Edit the Page you want to set as main page) => Select Main Page template and then update.

In the same way, prepare a separate common template for other pages with same layout and apply it to them.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use it as a template, then you need to set it as a template page, and in wordpress, when create the page, set the template to that:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

If not, then load the `document_root/wp-load.php`